# Autofilter values contains the Asterisk (*)

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

On Excel, I can use tilde (`~`) before Asterisk (`*`) to filter of values contains the asterisk (`*`) and it works.
I tried the same on VBA, But It didn't work at all (the result is null values).
I have many values contains the asterisk (*) as a string like ( `8*16` , `10*11`).
kindly , how to fix this issue without replacing the asterisk on my main dataset.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub AutoFilter_on_Asterisk()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
     Set ws = ActiveSheet
      Set rng = ws.Range("A3:AH7000")
    
    rng.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="~*", Operator:=xlFilterValues  'the result is null values
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde "escapes" the asterix character to signal that you don't want to use it as wildcard, but as character. If you enter `X` as criteria, Excel will show you all rows that are *exactly* `X`. If you want to get all rows where the value *contains* an `X`, you can either enter `*X*` in the search field, or you use the "TextFilters->Contains..." dialog (which will do the same search, only that you don't need to know that the asterix is the wildcard character).

Searching for an asterix is exactly the same: Your code searches for rows that contain only an asterix (and as you don't have any, your result is empty). Your search text needs to be `*~**`:

```
rng.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="*~**", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```